# Zoom window in GNOME overview mode

Tags: gnome

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 (GNOME version).

In 12.04 when I entered overview mode, I could zoom any window shown by moving mouse pointer over it and using mouse wheel. This has no effect in 14.04.

Is it possible to enable this functionality in 14.04 and how?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, just discovered someone decided this feature was not really useful and was removed.

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=686639